# Iterative Imputer by sklearn adding rows to Test data set during imputation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm participating in the data the data sci project on Kaggle to learn more about Python, and am using the Iterative Imputer to estimate age for both the training and test data set.

The training data set is 891 rows, and the test data set is 418.

After transforming the test data set to impute the values using the imputer fit with the training data set, it adds rows to make the test data set 891 rows, also.

Any assistance is very welcome.

```
imp = IterativeImputer(max_iter=10, random_state = 1001, min_value=18, max_value=80, missing_values = np.nan)
features = ['Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp','Parch', 'female', 'male', 'Cherbourg','Queenstown','Southampton']
train_df[features] = imp.fit(train_df[features])
#train_df[features] = imp.transform(train_df[features]) 
test_df[features] = imp.transform(test_df[features])
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! The documentation says `IterativeImputer().transform(X)` returns a numpy array of the same shape as `X`, so perhaps check what you put in the method. When asking questions, you can try to post a minimum reproducible example with a a few lines of data. Here's a link with tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thomas, Thank you for your tip. You're correct: I went through and checked what I put in using test_df.shape and along the way I had accidentally applied train_df at some point to test_df. Needless to say, by the time I got to this specific code above, I had a larger array than what I was looking for. Just needed to freshen my eyes up. Thanks again.